# PHP random value from a possible 5 items with multiple items for each

Tags: php

I will try to explain this the best I can. I need to generate a random value (colour) based on the amount of items left in each item.

Say I have 5 colours and each colour has 10 spots available:

```
Red = 10
Blue = 10
Green = 10
Yellow = 10
Black = 10
```

I would like to get the first random colour with each colour having an equal chance because they all have 10 spots available. Then if the first value picked is Red then the list will look like

```
Red = 9
Blue = 10
Green = 10
Yellow = 10
Black = 10
```

Then the next random value will weight Red slightly lower because the spots available in the other colours are higher. Let say Red was picked again then the list will look like:

```
Red = 8
Blue = 10
Green = 10
Yellow = 10
Black = 10
```

so then the next round would weight Red even lower still.

Basically I would like each spot to have an equal chance of being picked equally but distribute the spots evenly (without going sequential).

The colours could be more or less than 5 and the spots available could be up to 1000. The data will be stored in a DB but there could be multiple spot requests per second so any suggestions on how to store this data is also appreciated. Once a spot is requested it is removed from the colour group.

Many many thanks!

Comment: Didn't get what you want you what will happen if Red=0?

Comment: So what have you tried to do to implement this?

Comment: Will the colors always start with equal numbers of spots? Also do the specific spots matter, as in a random number gives 7 so red 7 is taken, or just a red is taken so the total number available is reduced by 1?

Comment: @WebChemist yes each colour will have equal spots and when one is pick that colour will just be reduced by 1 so the random isn't picking a particular spot within a colour

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the items as weights and pick a random value and compare it with the weight. Work through the list  and subtract the weights from the random value until it's less than the list probability. In the next iteration when the item is used the probabilities changes until it's empty.

```
   x = random([0.0, 1.0])
   for i in 0..n
       if x < probabilities[i]
        choose(i)
         break
       else
         x -= probabilities[i]
     end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store spots in a database I would have take another approach than the other solutions.

To model it so that several threads can take a available color each you might as well have a table of spots that indicates their color as a set or foreign key and a lease id that has unique key and default NULL.

You select a random element by first updating a random row that is not already leased with a lease id (uuid). From there on other requests cannot choose that one any more and you can do a select query by lease id to find out what color it is. This will ensure there will be no race conditions and you can serve several clients at the same time with row based locking.

With 10,000 spots you store a color and a lease id, so it will be less than 80kB. The whole table will be in cache at all times.

Comment: Hi I did think about this approach but there maybe upto 2 million spots available and hundreds of threads at once. Maybe another DB engine other than MySQL?

Comment: Mysql with Innodb should do fine since it has row based locking. I don't think 2 million rows will be a problem either. The key is to not get race conditions.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this. Suppose you have an array like you mentioned, with data coming off the DB:

```
red   => 100
green => 200
blue  =>  50
```

Add the values of all the colors combined (350 in this case). Pick a random value between 1 and that.

```
$randValue = rand(1, 350);
```

Then use a loop to progressively substract the values of the colors until you're left with 0 or a negative:

```
foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
    $randValue = $randValue - $value;
    if ($randValue < 1) {
        $pickedColor = $key;
        // and substract 1 from this color in the DB
        break;
    }
}
```

So, in this case, if `$randValue` was 124, you would get green.